# Problems ReRendering a Table

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, rerender, actionfunction

I am trying to rerender a table in response to a toggle switch change.  My switch calls a Javascript function:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkPractice" onchange="flickSwitch()" />
```

The JS function looks like this:

```
function flickSwitch()
{
    // called when we click the switch on or off
    var OnOff = $("#chkPractice").val();
    alert("Switch: " + OnOff);  // on indicates practice TRUE
    CallSetPracticeFlag(OnOff);
}
```

I see the alert so I know this is being called when I click the switch.  The JS calls an action function:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="CallSetPracticeFlag" action="{!setPracticeFlag}"  
       rerender="hoursRepeater" onComplete="alert('Set Flag');">
                <apex:param id="pFlag" name="Flag" value=""/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

Once again, I know this is being called because I see the alert indicating that it has completed.  I am trying to update a table on the page:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!available_hours}" var="h" id="hoursRepeater">
              <tr>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Day__c}" /></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Start_Time__c}"/></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.End_Time__c}"/></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Appointment_Type_Name__c}"/></td>
              </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
```

But the repeater never reloads the data.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

apex:repeat doesn't actually generate an ID within the the DOM structure, and so it cannot be directly targeted. You need to wrap that element within a parent element, and rerender that instead. You can use almost any sort of wrapper element, such as apex:outputText, apex:outputPanel, apex:form (but don't nest forms), apex:tab if you're using apex:tabPanel, and so on.

```
<apex:outputText id="hoursRepeater">
<apex:repeat value="{!available_hours}" var="h">
              <tr>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Day__c}" /></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Start_Time__c}"/></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.End_Time__c}"/></td>
                <td><apex:outputField value="{!h.Appointment_Type_Name__c}"/></td>
              </tr>
 </apex:repeat>
</apex:outputText>
```

Comment: Thanks much.  I did as you suggested, and also fixed another bug I found.  I was evaluating checked/unchecked for my checkbox using the .val() function which is incorrect.  I changed the JS Function to use .is(":checked"); instead which works.  I see via System.Debug statements that my controller function to refresh the data is being called and returning the correct number of records.  But the page itself does not update; it still shows the old data.  So it appears I am still missing something.

Comment: Problem solved: wrapped the entire table (not just the repeater) in an <apex:OutputPanel> and this resolved the issue, it's updating just fine now.